# Jquery Not Working (Maybe AJAX reload - or maybe just bad syntax?)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using this Jquery :

```
$('#resultstable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
alert("helloworld") 
$('#resultstable tr.Selected').removeClass('Selected');
$(this).addClass('Selected');
});
```

Which should add the class Selected to a TR when it it clicked. It should also remove any other instance of a class selected. (Only one TR can be selected at one time)

It is working on this table :

```
        <table id="resultstable">

            <tr id="resultsheading">
                <th OnClick="OrderBy(0)">Module<br /> Code</th>
                <th OnClick="OrderBy(1)">RoomID</th>
                <th OnClick="OrderBy(2)">Students</th>

                <th OnClick="OrderBy(3)">Priority</th>
                <th OnClick="OrderBy(4)">Weeks</th>
                <th OnClick="OrderBy(5)">Day</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>End Time</th>

                <th OnClick="OrderBy(6)">Date Added</th>
            </tr>
<tbody>
    <tr id= "192" > 
        <td>11COA121</td>
        <td>CC012</td>
        <td>340</td>
        <td>Yes</td>

        <td>All</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>

    </tr>       
</tbody>
</table>
```

I should also mention that the table is dynamic and when a user clicks a button such as edit or delete it will delete that row and then reload the table using this (For example to delete a row) :

```
function DeleteRequest(ReqID)
    {
        //Ajax call for deleterequest
        $.post("a/outputresults2.php", {DelRequest: ReqID} , function(data)
{
            $('#resultstable').html(data);
            });

    }
```

At the moment, it is not doing anything and not even running through, it is not alerting. What is the issue?

Should note, no errors on JS console coming up though.

Thank you!

Comment: It runs for me: http://jsfiddle.net/T9gdA/1/

Comment: It works for me too, in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML returned by your AJAX call, the problem may be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is this line

```
$('#resultstable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
```

If I understand this correctly, the selector you put will attach event handlers to the tbody and tr elements currently inside the table, so when you add new tr elements, the event handler will not be triggered for new rows.

You could try with something like

```
$('#resultstable').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('tr') || $(event.target).is('tbody')) {
        // ... do logic in here
    }
});
```

Basically filter the target to tr or tbody yourself based on the event.target property.

Answer (score 0):

The selection work with this code.

Se jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/fUntG/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may need to change:

```
$('#resultstable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
```

to:

```
$('#resultstable').live('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
```

so it continues to work with dynamically loaded data.

Comment: `on` and `live` = the same thing .... As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to .live().

Comment: For some reason it is working with .live and not with .on. BUT. The ($this) bit isn't working. I've got a feeling its erroring because its dynamically being updated. Any ideas?

Comment: You may trying assigning `var row = $(this);` before adding and removing classes to ensure $(this) isn't referencing another object. Obviously, your syntax would be `row.addClass('Selected')`.